Problem 6.8 in Fulton's Algebraic Curves: the nonvanishing locus of a regular function is open
Question: Let $U$ be an open subset of a variety $V$, $z\in k(V)$. Suppose $z\in O_p(V)$ for all $P\in U$. Show that $U_z = \lbrace P\in U \mid z(P) \ne 0 \rbrace $ is open.
Attempt: Initially I want to write $z = f/g$ and choose $F$ such that $\bar{F} = f$,  then $U - U_z = U\cap V(F)$ is closed and $U$ is open. But I note that though for each $P$, $z$ can be written like this type, there may not exist $g$ such that $g(P)\ne 0$ for each $P$.
So then I get stuck. I think I miss something and really need some help. Thanks in advance!

You're on the right track - you have the correct idea, you just need a little help with the implementation.
Saying $z$ is regular at $p\in V$ means that there is an open neighborhood $p\in W_p\subset V$ and two polynomial functions $f,g$ on $W$ so that $g(q)\neq 0$ for all $q\in W_p$ and $z=f/g$ on $W_p$. If $z(p)\neq 0$, then the vanishing locus of $f$ avoids $p$, so we can find an open neighborhood $W_p'\subset W_p$ so that $z=f/g$ on $W_p'$ and $z=f/g$ does not vanish anywhere on $W_p'$. This shows that $U_z = \bigcup_{p\in U_z} W_p'$ is open.
